# Allow user to edit a blog post live with Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm making a blog feature on a website and I want to allow the User to edit the text of the post without taking them to a different view. Just like you can edit a post on Facebook, or on Stack. This is just the piece of code containing the form.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <button style="text-align:left;" class="content-editor">
         <!-- line displays the text, I want to be able to make this editable on click -->
         <p  class='body-font'>{{ post_detail.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
<!--the actual form that allows you edit, obviously it's just sitting there right now -->
     <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
         {{ form.as_p }}
         <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
     </form>
     </button>
 {% endif %}
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, in my mind when the button is clicked, I should have some HTML that appears and replaces the HTML that was displaying just the text. The new editable text would be a model that is created by and passed from a view right?

Comment: in that form tag you can give `action='url'`, so give the url of the page you want to redirect and edit.

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? [Django CMS](https://www.django-cms.org/) offers something similar and it is the right application for your use case.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems with that I would need to start a new project, is that true? I already have a project started and was just trying to implement this one feature

Comment: @VikasDamodar That's what I had before, it would redirect to the page where they could edit the post. But I want to edit it right there, the same way we can say edit a comment right here

Comment: @Amon then you make that form in editable format with js or something and in the same view class you give another post method to save and return edited data to the same page